# Interpretation of Coefficients in Regression

Tags: regression

Consider the standard form of linear regression:

$$Y_i = \beta_0+\beta_{1}x_{i} +\epsilon_i \ \text{for} \ i = 1 \dots n$$

We can rewrite this as $$Y_i = (\beta_0+\beta_{1}\bar{x})+\beta_{1}(x_i-\bar{x}) + \epsilon_i \ \text{for} \ i = 1 \dots n$$

If we let $\alpha = \beta_0+\beta_{1}\bar{x}$, then $$Y_i = \alpha+\beta_{1}(x_i-\bar{x}) + \epsilon_i \ \text{for} \ i = 1 \dots n$$

What is the interpretation of $\alpha$? Would it be the value of $Y_i$ at $x_i = \bar{x}$?

Comment: but you've got the equation for alpha written right there... what more can you want? you could think of it as kind of the centre point of the regression line.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all this, just take the expectation of left and right sides of main model equation:
$$E[Y]=\beta_0+\beta_1E[X]\equiv\alpha$$

In fact, this shows a very important role of the intercept in OLS: it allows for errors to have mean zero. Think of this if there was no intercept, then you can't have a balance because $$E[Y]\ne \beta_1 E[X]$$

So, you'll be forced to have
$$E[Y]=\beta_1E[X]+E[e],$$
where $E[e]=E[Y]-\beta_1E[X]\ne 0$